# Как закрыть программу так, чтобы она закрылась вся?

Tags: c#

Всем привет.

Как полностью закрыть программу? Если я нажимаю Выход, происходит

```
this.Close();
```

Но потом открывается другая форма, а как закрыть вообще всю программу?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Application.Exit();
```

или

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```

Answer (score 8):

- Простое закрытие: `Application.Shutdown`.
- Вынужденное закрытие: `Environment.FailFast`.

Answer (score 1):

Application.Current.Shutdown();