# Закрытие обрамляющей MDI формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте.
В классе дочерней формы определено событие FormClosing, в котором сохраняются данные с формы в некоторый файл перед закрытием.

```
        if (this.Text.Contains("txt"))
        {
            string path= @"D:\SaveFiles\"+this.Text+".txt";
            File.WriteAllLines(path, textBox1.Lines);
        }
        else
        {
            SaveAs sva = new SaveAs();
            sva.ShowDialog();
            string path=@"D:\SaveFiles\" + sva.textBox1.Text + ".txt";
            File.WriteAllLines(path, textBox1.Lines);
        }
```

С закрытием дочерней формы все хорошо. Но вот при попытке закрыть обрамляющую форму приходиться сначала закрывать все дочерние (вызывается событие FormClosing дочерних форм), как исправить, чтобы можно было закрыть сразу все приложение. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я если я верно понял, то при закрытии дочерней формы, вы смотрите, а был ли когда-то набранный текст сохранен в файл, и, если да, то молча сохраняете изменения в этот файл и закрываете форму.

Если же в дочерней MDI форме текст был набран, но в файл не сохранялся, то предлагаете это сделать и вызываете диалог сохранения.

При закрытии основной формы у вас отрабатывает этот механизм для каждой из открытых дочерних MDI-форм и диалог сохранения изменений появляется для каждой из дочерних форм, где текст не был сохранен.

Так вот, вообще у вас верный подход с точки зрения пользователя, так как было бы обидно, если при закрытии приложения изменения текста в MDI-формах просто бы пропали.

Могу рекомендовать поступить следующим образом: в родительской форме создайте дополнительное публичное свойство `public bool SaveChangesFromMDI {get; set;}`. При инициализации главной формы установите это свойство в `True`, или, если у вас C# 6.0 и VS 2015, можно сразу так: `public bool SaveChangesFromMDI { get; set; } = true;`

Далее в обработчик `FormClosing` главной формы добавьте примерно такой код:

```
    private void FormMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SaveChangesFromMDI)
        {
            //Пробежимся по всем MDI формам и посмотрим, а есть ли там что сохранять?
            bool ShowSaveQuery = false;
            for (int x = 0; x < this.MdiChildren.Length; x++)
            {
                if (!((Form)this.MdiChildren[x]).Text.Contains(".txt"))
                {   
                    //В какой-то из форм нашелся не сохраненный текст, тогда установим флаг,
                    //что нам нужно показать запрос на сохранение данных
                    ShowSaveQuery = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            DialogResult dr = DialogResult.None;
            //Если нужно показать запрос, то показываем его, что бы потом проанализировать решение пользователя
            if (ShowSaveQuery)
            {
                dr = MessageBox.Show("Имеются несохраненные данные в открытых документах. Сохранять эти данные?", "Выход", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            }

            //Смотрим, что же выбрал пользователь, да и выбрал ли?
            switch (dr)
            {
                case DialogResult.Yes:
                    //Пользователь хочет сохранять данные
                    SaveChangesFromMDI = true;
                    break;
                case DialogResult.None:
                case DialogResult.No:
                    //Не нужно сохранять данные
                    SaveChangesFromMDI = false;
                    break;
                case DialogResult.Cancel:
                    //Пользователь передумал завершать работу, отменяем закрытие приложения.
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
            }

            //А теперь в цикле мы можем принудительно позакрывать дочерние формы:
            for (int x = 0; x < this.MdiChildren.Length; x++)
            {
                ((Form)this.MdiChildren[x]).Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Но что бы дочерние формы у нас знали что делать, основываясь на выборе юзера, то код их обработчика события `FormClosing` нужно чуть-чуть дополнить, например, так:

```
            ...
            if (MainForm.SaveChangesFromMDI)
            {
                if (this.Text.Contains("txt"))
                {
                    string path = @"D:\SaveFiles\" + this.Text + ".txt";
                    File.WriteAllLines(path, textBox1.Lines);
                }
                else
                {
                    SaveAs sva = new SaveAs();
                    sva.ShowDialog();
                    string path = @"D:\SaveFiles\" + sva.textBox1.Text + ".txt";
                    File.WriteAllLines(path, textBox1.Lines);
                }
            }
```

Т.е. из дочерней MDI-формы мы смотрим в родительскую, на значение свойства `SaveChangesFromMDI`, и если оно `true`, то вызываем ваш механизм сохранения, а если пользователь решил ничего не сохранять, то оно будет `false` и ничего не сохранится, никаких диалогов сохранения показано не будет.

Вы можете сделать несколько иную логику, конечно, это уже как вам удобнее.

---

Еще вариантом выхода из приложения будет вызов `Environment.FailFast(null)`, но это хоть и сработает, но способ не правильный, т.к. это аварийное завершение по сути.

И еще можно посмотреть ответы на [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/95011/222168) про завершение работы приложения.